# jQuery cross-browser "scroll to top", with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

Right now I'm using this:

```
$('#go-to-top').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){ 
    $('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); return true; 
  });
});
```

which doesn't work in Chrome, and in Opera I get a small flicker: the browser instantly scrolls to the top, then back to the bottom and then it begins to scroll slowly back to top, like it should.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that `#go-to-top` is an element _ID_, which must be unique. Calling `each` on something that _should_ only contain one element may work, but is naughty. Probably you want to give your elements a _class_ instead, and select with `$('.go-to-top')`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You're returning `true` from the click function, so it won't prevent the default browser behaviour (i.e. navigating to the`go-to-top` anchor. As Mark has said, use:

`$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');`

So your code should now look like:

```
$('#go-to-top').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){ 
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: that was it, with return set to `false` it scrolls :D

Comment: Still the `each` is absolutely unneccessary. Even if there were multiple elements with the id go-to-top, then `click` on its own would be more than enought!

Comment: Using html,body will cause the callback to fire twice. Just using html works for me.

Comment: Sorry, using `html,body` does not cause the callback to fire twice. Indeed, it is needed for certain browsers.

Answer (score 5):

To get it to work in opera this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880743/jquery-animate-scrolltop-on-opera-bug/4915885#4915885) proved helpful.

Putting that with your `click()`

```
$(this).click(function() {
    $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 'slow');
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/7ZyeZ/1/).**

*Side note* if all you are doing with the `.each()` is assigning a click handler you do not need to iterate over the collection it can be simplified to this:

```
$('#go-to-top').click(function(){ 
    $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
});
```

Also if there is more than one element with id `#go-to-top` your markup will be invalid, try switching it to a class `.go-to-top`

Comment: Since then, Opera has switched to the WebKit engine, so I guess the special handling for it is no longer needed, and probably even harmful.

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

aswell as the html one.

edit >

```
$('#go-to-top').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){ 
    $('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); return true; 
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); return true; 
    $('document').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); return true; 
    $('window').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); return true; 
  });
});
```

should cover all browsers!

Comment: Using `return true` on l.3 will prevent any following statement to be executed

Answer (score 1):

Hm... strange, with jsFiddle I can get it to work fine in Opera (ver 11.01), but in Chrome it just jumps up to the top and doesn't animate it like you want to.

You can se the jsFiddle here if you want to:
http://jsfiddle.net/H7RFU/

I hope that helps a bit, though it's not really an answer.

If what I have made isn't what your html etc looks like, please update it and add it.

Best regards,

Christian

Caveat: I haven't used the save function of jsFiddle before so I dunno for how long it it saved.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

It works cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

This will be working in all browsers. It avoids the hash tag on the url, so, the smooth scroll is done!

```
 $('#back-top a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {

        $('html,body').animate({

          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this, This is also simple

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var a = 400,
t = 1200,
l = 700,
s = e(".scrool-top");
e(window).scroll(function() {
e(this).scrollTop() > a ? s.addClass("scrool-is-visible") : s.removeClass("scrool-is-visible scrool-fade-out"), e(this).scrollTop() > t && s.addClass("scrool-fade-out")
}), s.on("click", function(a) {
a.preventDefault(), e("body,html").animate({
scrollTop: 0
}, l)
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a smooth solution in two ways: smooth scrolling and a smooth button.

With JavaScript disabled, it´s just a link on the bottom of the page to the anchor `top`.
(`#` as href can be pretty unstable.)

With JavaScript enabled:

1. Hide the div containing the link (to avoid flickering).
2. Fix the position of the div at the bottom right border of the window.
3. Remove the `href` attribute and add `click` handler for smooth scrolling.
   (keeps URL and browser history tidy and I need no `return` or `preventDefault` in the scrolling function)
4. Fade div in / out depending on scroll position:
   Display link only if scroll position > window height.
5. Update the position on resize.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <a name="top"></a>
    ...
    <div id="scrolltotop" style="display:block;text-align:right">
        <a href="#top" title="scroll to top"><img src="scrolltotop.png" alt="scroll to top"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```javascript
function scrolltotop_display()
{
    var el=$('#scrolltotop');
    if((window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop)>window.innerHeight)
    { if(!el.is(':visible')) { el.stop(true, true).fadeIn(); } }
    else { if(!el.is(':animated')) { el.stop(true, true).fadeOut(); }}
}
function scrolltotop_position()
{
    var el=$('#scrolltotop');
    el.css('top', window.innerHeight-100);
    el.css('left', window.innerWidth-100);
    scrolltotop_display();
}
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('#scrolltotop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#scrollToTop').css('position', 'fixed');
    scrolltotop_position();
    $('#scrollToTop a').removeAttr('href');
    $('#scrollToTop a').on('click', function(){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);});
});
$(window).on('scroll', scrolltotop_display);
$(window).on('resize', scrolltotop_position);
```