# How to make slow the Scroll-Top Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

ScrollTop is a jquery plugin *(go to top of page)*, trying to make slow Scroll Speed, but not working. I have changed `scrollSpeed : 'fast',` to `scrollSpeed : 'slow',` but it still fast, nothing change.

**JS:**

```
$.fn.extend({

    addScrollTop: function(options) {

        var defaults = {
                useObjWindow : false,
                scrollSpeed : 'fast',
                zIndex: '99'
            }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

        if($('body').find('.scrollTop-btn').length == 0) {
            $('body').append('<div class="scrollTop-btn" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></div>');
        }

        if(options.useObjWindow) {
            var parentWindow = this;
            var scrollWindow = this;
        }
        else {
            var parentWindow = window;
            var scrollWindow = 'html, body';
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.scrollTop-btn').on('click', function() {
                $(scrollWindow).animate({scrollTop:0}, options.scrollSpeed);
            });

            $(parentWindow).scroll(function() { 
                $('.scrollTop-btn').hide();
                var aTop = $('.scrollTop-btn').height() + 20;

                if($(this).scrollTop() >= (aTop + 20)) {
                    $('.scrollTop-btn').css('z-index', options.zIndex);
                    $('.scrollTop-btn').show();
                }
                else {
                    if($('.scrollTop-btn').is(":visible")) {
                        $('.scrollTop-btn').hide();
                    }
                }

            });


        });
    }

});
```

**Call:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("body").addScrollTop();
});
```

How to make it slower or smoother, when it go to top?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use jquery animate()

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

refer this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580350/jquery-cross-browser-scroll-to-top-with-animation)

Comment: Thanks, but how to call my plugin by your code? want solution for my plugin.

Comment: your plugin is working.. remove display:none; from div

Comment: Yes i know, but it's go to top speed is very fast, I'm trying to make it slow, how to this?

Comment: you set milliseconds instead of 'slow'.. $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);   or   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);

Comment: i have tryid but not working. `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("body").addScrollTop();
}, 5000); `

Comment: set options.scrollSpeed = 2000. it slow down and I can see it works in my test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95011/discussion-between-aabira-and-azzi).

Answer (score 9):

Only with CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I was searching for jQuery code to achieve this smooth effect, but none of them worked.

Comment: @Prathamesh Doke Cool , thanks for these beautiful phrases :)

Comment: Sorry dear, not solve scrolling problem in mobile devices. Thanks

Comment: Works just find for me on my android phone, both with Firefox and Chrome. Perfect solution.

Comment: This doesn't control speed; it just applies a default speed.

Answer (score 5):

### **Using jQuery**

If you want you can customize how much time you would like the "scrolling" to last. Or do something else when scroll effect is finished.

I have a: `<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">`

And want to scroll to an element with class "beginning"

```
$('.scrollToTop').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $('.beginning').offset().top}, 500);
 });
```

The last part where you have the 500. You can set there how much time you want the effect to last. In milliseconds.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'slow' with  - Ex. 1000, 5000, 10000

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, <milliseconds>);

// Scroll 2 sec
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);

// Scroll 5 sec
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 5000);
```