# Scroll event not working on chrome and not precise in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to build a custom scroll for my website but it's not perfect and I don't know how to improve it. It should scroll from one position to another  specific position but there is a difference of  pixels that become bigger every scroll events. It also seems to not work on chrome.

here is a link to the html file :http://infographie.inraci.be/blc/blc.html

here is the code :

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){

var hauteur5 = $(window).height();
var scroll5 = $(window).scrollTop();

         if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {

        $(window).scrollTo(scroll5-hauteur5/4,1,function(){

      })
} else { 
  $(window).scrollTo(scroll5+hauteur5/4,1,function(){
 })
  }
 });
```

Comment: have you tried changing it so it uses the document instead of the window?

Comment: i just tried but it doesn't seems to work better.

Comment: also, use the generic `$(document).on('scroll')` instead of getting all fancy.. jQuery is meant to handle browser inconsistencies so let it

Comment: when i use $(document).on('scroll') it doesn't work on both of them

Comment: i found why it was not really smooth in google chrome. I just put overflow hidden on the boddy and now it's working in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want check this snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572744/3605379

There I check the week speed with a timeout. Play with it so you can get the timing right.

Comment: thanks but i dont know how to use that to resolve my problem

Comment: Sorry. I would look in your code where you set where each element is on the browser. For me would be easier to just use "$(".elementClass.").scrollTo() and not use the height or position, since it will change when you resize the browser.

Comment: As it measure the height every time i scroll it does not  matter if i resize the window? i m sorry i m not using jquery so much so maybe i don't get it.

Comment: For now i ve solve it with your idea of  "$(".elementClass.").scrollTo(). thanks ... but as they  all  have the same classname , how can i scroll to the next row of elements?

Comment: for now ive use this solution, it works but its bad i think :)    
var zz=0
 $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){


   if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
zz-=5
var arr=$("#image"+zz);
if (zz<0){
 zz=0
} 

   $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $(arr).offset().top}, 0);
   
  } else

Comment: you can use parent, siblings, next or prev.