# How to make smoother scroll-to-top action

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code doing slow to fast movements  when i call scroll to top action any better solution to fix the smoothness?

my code:

```js
(function () {
    var top_link = '';
    top_link = $(".top");
    var pos = top_link.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
            top_link.fadeIn();
        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 150) {
            top_link.fadeOut();
        }
    });
})();

$(".top").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: try changing value 600 to some more or `slow`

Comment: if i put "slow"  just refresh

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686560/6309457

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make slow the Scroll-Top Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686523/how-to-make-slow-the-scroll-top-speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Update your Code :

```
(function () {
    var top_link = '';
    top_link = $(".top");
    var pos = top_link.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            top_link.fadeIn('slow');
        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 50) {
            top_link.fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
})();

$(".top").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: with this not even show  when you scroll down the icon

Comment: Please see the Update

Comment: not working  start slow and then start speed up to the top

Comment: Just change 50 to 150 for the two conditions

Comment: this will be the same as i have before  not working