# How to slow down scroll to top speed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following simple `scrollTop()` function obtained from w3schools. The issue i have is setting the time for scrolling. Different people gave different methods and everyone removed one or all lines from the following code. I'm waiting for a function which can be added to set the scrolling speed and no other text is to be removed. Here's the codepen work https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/zYqQbmM

```js
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible
  <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong></div>
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686523/how-to-make-slow-the-scroll-top-speed/33686560

Comment: Check out the scrollTo function, setting behavior: 'smooth', you'll need to confirm your required browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: @LahiruTM, I've seen that. But i have already mentioned that i  want to make only additions in following code. Cam you make amy additions in following code?

Comment: @emiliokyp, `scroll behavior: smooth` is already added in the css. I want to control it's time. See, example, the scroll top function needs to happen in 8 seconds

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation

Comment: Load Jquery in script section. then comment two lines in top function and put this. ***$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pure Javascript solution. you may need to remove `scroll-behavior: smooth` style as this interrupts slow scrolling. in javascript `scrollTo` function provide the second parameters in `milliseconds` and function will take that much time to scroll to top.

JS code referred from the answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844067

```js
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// Bind your button click, scroll direction and effect speed
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
  scrollTo(0, 8000); // it will take 8 seconds to reach to top.

}

// Element to move, time in ms to animate
function scrollTo(element, duration) {
  var e = document.documentElement;
  if (e.scrollTop === 0) {
    var t = e.scrollTop;
    ++e.scrollTop;
    e = t + 1 === e.scrollTop-- ? e : document.body;
  }
  scrollToC(e, e.scrollTop, element, duration);
}

// Element to move, element or px from, element or px to, time in ms to animate
function scrollToC(element, from, to, duration) {
  if (duration <= 0) return;
  if (typeof from === "object") from = from.offsetTop;
  if (typeof to === "object") to = to.offsetTop;

  scrollToX(element, from, to, 0, 1 / duration, 20, easeOutCuaic);
}

function scrollToX(element, xFrom, xTo, t01, speed, step, motion) {
  if (t01 < 0 || t01 > 1 || speed <= 0) {
    element.scrollTop = xTo;
    return;
  }
  element.scrollTop = xFrom - (xFrom - xTo) * motion(t01);
  t01 += speed * step;
  debugger;
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollToX(element, xFrom, xTo, t01, speed, step, motion);
  }, step);
}

function easeOutCuaic(t) {
  t--;
  return t * t * t + 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible
  <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to slow down the scroll speed by using javascript

**This work for me**

```
// Set the scroll speed factor
let scrollSpeed = 0.5;

// Add an event listener for the 'wheel' event
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  // Prevent default scrolling behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Calculate the new scroll position
  let delta = event.deltaY;
  let scrollPosition = window.scrollY + (delta * scrollSpeed);

  // Set the new scroll position
  window.scrollTo({
    top: scrollPosition,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: interesting approach, but even with scrollSpeed of 1.0 it is slower than normal

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the smooth scroll using

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Note that it's not supported by Safari yet :/ ([check here](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior))

Also there is [Smooth Scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll) GitHub repo by Ferdinandi I think it helps, just take a look at it and it's features.

Answer (score 0):

animated-scroll-to
it works find.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/animated-scroll-to

```
animateScrollTo(el as Element, {
    elementToScroll: elContainer,
    speed: 100,
}).then();
```