# Navigation buttons are not clickable on my bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to customise a single page bootstrap template into a multi-page. I have duplicated the index page and then tweaked them into services, et al. I've got the href pointing to these new pages, but the navbar buttons are not clickable. I suspect the JS is not built for multiple pages, but I don't have the know-how to deal with JS.

If someone here would care to look at it for me, the code/script is:

`

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>             <!-- jQuery (https://jquery.com/download/) -->
    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                 <!-- Bootstrap (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js"></script>      <!-- Single Page Nav (https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav) -->
    
    <!-- Templatemo scripts -->
    <script>     

    var bigNavbarHeight = 90;
    var smallNavbarHeight = 68;
    var navbarHeight = bigNavbarHeight;                 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var topOffset = 180;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
           
            if($(this).scrollTop() > topOffset) {
                $(".navbar-container").addClass("sticky");
            }
            else {
                $(".navbar-container").removeClass("sticky");
            }

        });

        /* Single page nav
        -----------------------------------------*/

        if($(window).width() < 992) {
            navbarHeight = smallNavbarHeight;
        }

        $('#tmNavbar').singlePageNav({
           'currentClass' : "active",
            offset : navbarHeight
        });


        /* Collapse menu after click 
           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#tmNavbar').on("click", "a", null, function () {
            $('#tmNavbar').collapse('hide');               
        });

        // Handle nav offset upon window resize
        $(window).resize(function(){
            if($(window).width() < 992) {
                navbarHeight = smallNavbarHeight;
            } else {
                navbarHeight = bigNavbarHeight;
            }

            $('#tmNavbar').singlePageNav({
                'currentClass' : "active",
                offset : navbarHeight
            });
        });
        

        /*  Scroll to top
            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580350/jquery-cross-browser-scroll-to-top-with-animation
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $('#go-to-top').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){ 
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                return false; 
            });
        });
        
    });

    </script>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, bootstrap hyperlink buttons don't need js to function.

If your hyperlink buttons are not working... You might want check a few things.

- is there a css conflict, resulting in your buttons not being click able, z-index is a common issue.
- is there any JS which calls e.preventDefault() on your hyperlinks, as that would block the normal behaviors.

You could add a little js in the console to aide in debugging `$('*').click(function(e){console.log(e)})` then click on your button and see what is logged, or simply check the events panel in dev tools.

---

#### UPDATE: based on OP comments below...

Ok, so it was in-fact an issue with your JavaScript, specificly the 'jquery.singlePageNav.min.js' JavaScript file.

Here is where the issue lies:

```
handleClick: function( t ) {
        var n = this, r = t.currentTarget , i = e( r.hash );

            t.preventDefault(); <---- This prevents, the default behavior of anchor tags...
            
            if ( i.length ) {
                n.clearTimer();
                if ( typeof n.options.beforeStart === "function" ) {
                    n.options.beforeStart()
                }
                n.setActiveLink( r.hash );
                n.scrollTo( i, function() {
                    if ( n.options.updateHash && history.pushState ) {
                        history.pushState( null, null, r.hash )
                    }
                    n.setTimer();
                    if ( typeof n.options.onComplete === "function" ) {
                        n.options.onComplete()
                    }
                } )
            }
    }
```

I've patched the file, to allow "external" hrefs to work as expected.

```
handleClick: function( t ) {
            var n = this, r = t.currentTarget , i = e( r.hash );

            if((t.target.href.replace( document.URL, '')).replace(location.protocol+'//', '')[0]  === '#'){ // <-- this will permit "non leading #" urls to behave normally.

                t.preventDefault();
                
                if ( i.length ) {
                    n.clearTimer();
                    if ( typeof n.options.beforeStart === "function" ) {
                        n.options.beforeStart()
                    }
                    n.setActiveLink( r.hash );
                    n.scrollTo( i, function() {
                        if ( n.options.updateHash && history.pushState ) {
                            history.pushState( null, null, r.hash )
                        }
                        n.setTimer();
                        if ( typeof n.options.onComplete === "function" ) {
                            n.options.onComplete()
                        }
                    } )
                }
            }

            
        }
```

Here is an un-minified version with my patches:

```js
/**
 * Single Page Nav Plugin
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Chris Wojcik <hello@chriswojcik.net>
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * @author Chris Wojcik
 * @version 1.2.0
 * @modified to support external hyperlinks...
 */
if ( typeof Object.create !== "function" ) {
    Object.create = function( e ) {
        function t() {}
        t.prototype = e;
        return new t
    }
}( function( e, t, n, r ) {
    "use strict";
    var i = {
        init: function( n, r ) {
            this.options = e.extend( {}, e.fn.singlePageNav.defaults, n );
            this.container = r;
            this.$container = e( r );
            this.$links = this.$container.find( "a" );
            if ( this.options.filter !== "" ) {
                this.$links = this.$links.filter( this.options.filter )
            }
            this.$window = e( t );
            this.$htmlbody = e( "html, body" );
            this.$links.on( "click.singlePageNav", e.proxy( this.handleClick, this ) );
            this.didScroll = false;
            this.checkPosition();
            this.setTimer()
        }
        , handleClick: function( t ) {
            var n = this, r = t.currentTarget , i = e( r.hash );

            if((t.target.href.replace( document.URL, '')).replace(location.protocol+'//', '')[#] ){

                t.preventDefault();
                
                if ( i.length ) {
                    n.clearTimer();
                    if ( typeof n.options.beforeStart === "function" ) {
                        n.options.beforeStart()
                    }
                    n.setActiveLink( r.hash );
                    n.scrollTo( i, function() {
                        if ( n.options.updateHash && history.pushState ) {
                            history.pushState( null, null, r.hash )
                        }
                        n.setTimer();
                        if ( typeof n.options.onComplete === "function" ) {
                            n.options.onComplete()
                        }
                    } )
                }
            }

            
        }
        , scrollTo: function( e, t ) {
            var n = this;
            var r = n.getCoords( e ).top;
            var i = false;
            n.$htmlbody.stop().animate( {
                scrollTop: r
            }, {
                duration: n.options.speed
                , easing: n.options.easing
                , complete: function() {
                    if ( typeof t === "function" && !i ) {
                        t()
                    }
                    i = true
                }
            } )
        }
        , setTimer: function() {
            var e = this;
            e.$window.on( "scroll.singlePageNav", function() {
                e.didScroll = true
            } );
            e.timer = setInterval( function() {
                if ( e.didScroll ) {
                    e.didScroll = false;
                    e.checkPosition()
                }
            }, 250 )
        }
        , clearTimer: function() {
            clearInterval( this.timer );
            this.$window.off( "scroll.singlePageNav" );
            this.didScroll = false
        }
        , checkPosition: function() {
            var e = this.$window.scrollTop();
            var t = this.getCurrentSection( e );
            this.setActiveLink( t )
        }
        , getCoords: function( e ) {
            return {
                top: Math.round( e.offset().top ) - this.options.offset
            }
        }
        , setActiveLink: function( e ) {
            var t = this.$container.find( "a[href$='" + e + "']" );
            if ( !t.hasClass( this.options.currentClass ) ) {
                this.$links.removeClass( this.options.currentClass );
                t.addClass( this.options.currentClass )
            }
        }
        , getCurrentSection: function( t ) {
            var n, r, i, s;
            for ( n = 0; n < this.$links.length; n++ ) {
                r = this.$links[ n ].hash;
                if ( e( r ).length ) {
                    i = this.getCoords( e( r ) );
                    if ( t >= i.top - this.options.threshold ) {
                        s = r
                    }
                }
            }
            return s || this.$links[ 0 ].hash
        }
    };
    e.fn.singlePageNav = function( e ) {
        return this.each( function() {
            var t = Object.create( i );
            t.init( e, this )
        } )
    };
    e.fn.singlePageNav.defaults = {
        offset: 0
        , threshold: 120
        , speed: 400
        , currentClass: "current"
        , easing: "swing"
        , updateHash: false
        , filter: ""
        , onComplete: false
        , beforeStart: false
    }
} )( jQuery, window, document )
```

Alternatively, if you update your singlePageNav.js file to the newest version, [1.2.1](https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav), you could set it up to accomplish the same as my scripts above, by some simple configuration.

> Add the `.external` class to any links, which should be treated as "external"
>
> Then, ensure to update your .singlePageNav options, with:
>
> `$('#navigation-bar').singlePageNav({'filter': ':not(.external)'});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218403/discussion-between-user191110-and-rexfordkelly).

Comment: Just a quick update, my little problem is solved and thanks a lot for your help.