# Slide to Top on Refresh JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am using this code to get my page to go back to the top of the page upon refresh. However, I want it to SLIDE to the top with the same smoothness that my accordion does. Check it out in FF - Don't try this in IE9, there is a bug there I haven't figured out yet (unless you just feel like fixing that for me!).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1);
$('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1);
});
```

You can see it here: http://imip.rvadv.com/index3.html

On a more philosophical note: Is this a stupid idea? Should I really care about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter on the `animate()` method is in milliseconds.  Change it to `1000` and it should be fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000);
});
```

This might give you some cross-browser issues though, specifically in Opera, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880743/jquery-animate-scrolltop-on-opera-bug/4915885#4915885).

Comment: oh, duh. I tried taking off the html call and it didn't work.

Comment: Apologies! I updated my answer.  Take a look at that link if it's giving you problems in Opera.